# Android foreground service stops working at random periods of time

Tags: android, android-service

I need a long running service that should be stopped only by the user. I writed code for foreground service and it stops working after a while. One thing that I noticed was, that it stops working when phone's network is used by other applications(Messengers, Notifications).

What service does is, it gets information from the web and gives notification if there is a needed data appeared.

Here is the snippets of codes:

**onCreate**

```
public void onCreate() {
        // The service is being created
        MyService.noticedModes.clear();
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        // ....
        Notification notification;
        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
            notification = builder.getNotification();
        else
            notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(1244, notification);
    }
```

**onStartCommand**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

            if(mTimer != null) {
                mTimer.cancel();
            } else {
                // recreate new
                mTimer = new Timer();
            }
            // schedule task
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //AsyncTask starts
                        }

                    });
                }
            }, 0, CHECK_INTERVAL);

            pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WAKELOCK_TAG");
            wl.acquire();

            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }
    }
```

**onDestroy**

```
public void onDestroy() {
        wl.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

*** UPD: *** It stops working by itself, without throwing anything. Probably, Android is killing it. So, I need help in finding a way to let it run "forever", until user stops it by himself.

Also, after terminating it doesn't even go through onDestroy()

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it stops working" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Explained

Comment: "without throwing anything" -- how would you know? For example, in `onStartCommand()`, you are catching an exception without logging it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Aren't errors thrown when app is terminated because of them? In LogCat or debug mode apk?

Comment: Yes. However, your description fits a service that was terminated due to an unhandled exception, as `onDestroy()` will not be called and, AFAIK, Android will not try to restart the service (as you requested via `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`).

Comment: @Reminisce Did you manage to resolve this?